# Can the official OpenThread sniffer monitor a network formed by NCP devices?

Tags: sniffer, openthread

I want to form an **Openthread** network with three **Nordic nRF52840** cardboards. I would like to monitor the traffic using a sniffer, but i can't receive any data.

I used the official **Openthread** sniffer provided on Github : https://github.com/openthread/pyspinel,
and followed the tutorial : https://openthread.io/guides/ncp/sniffer.

The sniffer is working perfectly well on a network formed by Nordic cardboards flashed in **CLI**, but no data seems to be monitored in a network with **NCP** cardboards. Does anyone know is this sniffer can be used in **NPC** ?

Thanks !

Answer (score 0):

Couple of things to check:

1. Is the sniffer configured to the same channel as your NCP devices?
2. Is the sniffer device using the [pre-built NCP firmware](https://openthread.io/guides/ncp/firmware)?